# cancel gridview row edit mode programatically using C#

Tags: c#, gridview, buttonclick

I am using a Editable GridView. On clicking edit button  of a row, the row is coming in Editable mode and once I update the details of a current row, the row is getting saved and comes in normal mode.

Here I face one issue. When I make row to a Editable mode, On click of a button (which is not a part of grid) I want to bring Editable row mode to a normal mode.

Answer (score 7):

Change the gridview's EditIndex value to -1.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

You can put this in your "RowCancelingEdit" event

My Gridview name is grdViewDetails.

```
 protected void grdViewDetails_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
        {
            grdViewDetails.EditIndex = -1;
            grdViewDetails.DataSource = YourDatasource; //a dataset in my case

            //Bind data to the GridView control.
            grdViewDetails.DataBind();
        }
```